# How to move back from inherited resources gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

Recently I scaffold-ed two of my models/controllers/view, let's call them xxx and yyy. Now I look under the controller file, I see absolutely nothing ! but it was still functioning, upon investigation I found that was due to the

[inherited_resources Gem](https://github.com/josevalim/inherited_resources)

So the controllers look like this currently

```
class xxx < InheritedResources::Base
end
```

so if I change

```
InheritedResources::Base to ApplicationController
```

like I have it other controller, would it behave like normal controller ? I tried looking up on the docs, I was referred here for questions.

What is the best way to get normal controller/models back for those two scaffolds ?

Thanks for your time and help.

Answer (score 6):

in `config/application.rb` add:

```
#use rails scaffolding generator
config.app_generators.scaffold_controller = :scaffold_controller
```

Comment: Thanks! this was very helpful! Too bad the RailsApp composer prefers inherited resources over the resources gem.

Answer (score 0):

When you use `InheritedResources`, the gem registers a controller generator that generates just that, your controller definition. The point of using `InheritedResources::Base` is to clean your controllers and move all of the seven [REST](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Representational_state_transfer) actions to a common class. You don't need to define any of the following methods if you extend `InheritedResources::Base`

```
index
new
create
edit
update
show
destroy
```

They're all the defined for you. Go ahead and make a test, scaffold a resource and go to it's index method, add a couple records, play around...

Now if you really want to go back to the old way and have your code generated by the bundled controller generator, remove `inherited_resources` from your Gemfile, `bundle install`, and generate your scaffolds again.

Hope it helps (:

P.S. if you decide to use `InheritedResources` (which I suggest you do) you can overwrite any methods you want to customize. Have a [look at the docs](https://github.com/josevalim/inherited_resources), everything is more clear over there.